# Limiting usage of some service in MassTransit

Tags: c#, .net, masstransit

Lets say I want to limit usage of some services in the system. Every service triggered by publishing appropriate message to the bus. So, my idea right now is using [observing published messages](http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/observers.html#observing-published-messages) and check if message still allowed

```
public Task PrePublish<T>(PublishContext<T> context) where T : class
{
    if (typeof(IAction).GetTypeInfo().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T).GetTypeInfo()))
    {
        // check if action allowed here...

        throw new AccessDeniedException();
    }

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

how bad is this approach? Are there any better solutions?

Comment: Observers should not have any effect on messages or the pipeline. If you want to cancel the message processing, you need to create a middleware for this.

Comment: I'm not sure why/how you would do this on the producer end, are you hoping for some type of security? Because an application can get around this easily.

Comment: Sorry, @Chris, didn't get what you mean... I'm trying to setup some licensing module that will prevent using of some services, but have no idea yet what would be the best and easiest approach. I would much appreciate if you could share some experience.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any to share, I've never tried to restrict access to services via messaging.

Comment: How would you suggest to limit access to a service in this case? From the service?